# No MonetaryAmountsSingletonSpi loaded

Tags: java-money

Dependency added in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.money</groupId>
    <artifactId>money-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Relevant code:

```
MonetaryAmount mon = Monetary.getDefaultAmountFactory()
                        //getCurrency() returns String
                        .setCurrency(amount.getCurrency())
                        //getContent() returns BigDecimal
                        .setNumber(amount.getContent())
                        .create();
```

when unittesting i get this exception:

```
javax.money.MonetaryException: No MonetaryAmountsSingletonSpi loaded.

at javax.money.Monetary.lambda$getDefaultAmountFactory$13(Monetary.java:291)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaMoney is split into separate packages for API and implementation, but you added only the API to your POM. You also need an implementation, e.g. the reference implementation:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.javamoney</groupId>
  <artifactId>moneta</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```